# QtCreator: `clang: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)`

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang

I'm compiling my Qt 5.1.0 project in QtCreator, and I got the following output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ 
-c -pipe -O2 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -W -fPIE 
-DQT_NO_DEBUG 
-DQT_WIDGETS_LIB
-DQT_GUI_LIB
-DQT_CORE_LIB
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang
-I.
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/include
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtWidgets
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtGui
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/include/QtCore
-I../../../Qt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -Ibuild/debug/.moc
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers
-I.
-F/Users/apple/Qt/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib
-o build/debug/.obj/main.o ./main.cpp


clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
```

Version of XCode: 4.6.3

Version of Mac OS: 10.8.4

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use:

```
-stdlib=libstdc++
```

instead of:

```
-stdlib=libc++
```

This is because the `/usr/lib/libc++.dylib` is only installed on OSX 10.7+ and you have specified `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`.

You could also solve the issue by specifying: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` and leaving `-stdlib=libc++`, and this way you will get better C++11 support.

Comment: Thx~~ The Makefile is automatically generated from qmake, can I solve this by modifying my .pro file?

Comment: You probably can yes, to override the variables at fault, however a more long term solution is to modify the qmakespec file.